# phonegap store sqlite values to server machine

Tags: sqlite, cordova

I am creating a android application which works offline. I have use phonegap sqlite for storing the entry of the application. Now need to store the sqlite table to the server when the device is in online. I have no idea how to do this in phonegap. Please help me with this issue.. 
Thanks

Comment: Retrieve all the values and create JSON. That JSON can be transferred using ajax call in phonegap to the server. For more reference to retrieve the values, you can refer this link: http://docs.phonegap.com/en/1.3.0/phonegap_storage_storage.md.html

Comment: You can use [cordova-sqlite-porter](https://github.com/dpa99c/cordova-sqlite-porter#exportdbtojson) to create the JSON for you, then you just need to send it to your server

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use cordova-sqlite-porter to create the JSON from your stored data and then transfer it to your server via AJAX call.